# Losing connectivity in WSL2 after docker start

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I lose connectivity in my WSL2 when I start docker

```
$ curl google.fr                                                                                                    
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">


$ sudo service docker start

$ curl google.fr          
<timeout>
```

I know all about WSL2 connectivity issues with VPN and cisco anyconnect.
But in this particular case I'm not connected to any VPN.

To restore connectivity to the internet I have to do `wsl --shutdown` in PowerShell. But then I lose docker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple fix.

The pb commes from docker using the same network than WSL2.
To fix this issue you should explicitly tell docker to use a different network.

Add this to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "bip" : "10.10.0.1/16"
}
```

If the file doesn't already exists, create it.

Credits : https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-1180567785

---

Now that the `bip` is different you will probably need to update it on other technologies relying on docker. For instance on minikube you must define the new `bip` as a parameter during launch.
For ie :

```
minikube start --docker-opt bip=10.10.0.1/16
```

---

**EDIT**

Some time later all stoped working once again. To fix it I deactivated self generating resolv.conf (sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf) then killed wsl2 using powershell with `wsl --shutdown`. Opened a new shell, started docker then edited `/etc/resolv.conf` and replaced the content with `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. After exiting, internet connectivy was back.

Don't ask why ! Just have faith...